# Can I run PHP in Java?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc, formbuilder

I'm trying to make a form builder. I'm using SpringMVC.

I found this good form builder written in jQuery and PHP. [Jquery Formbuilder](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.formbuilder)

It converts an existing form(in DB) into JSON/XML and then passes it on for displaying. How can I achieve that in Spring? Is there a way I can reuse this plugin? Or use the PHP code inside Java directly?

Or is there a simpler way? Is there a similar plugin in Java?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP code in Java with [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp) but it seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Perhaps a simpler approach would be a PHP front end, populated by calls to a Java back-end

Comment: Yeah, Quercus seems like an overkill & the learning curve would be steep. What you suggest is correct but will require me to understand around 300 lines of PHP code and translate them to Java. :(

Comment: @LittleLebowski The PHP code is pretty straightforward so you won't be having a lot of trouble translating it to Java.